# Is it possible to @XmlSeeAlso on a class without no-args constructor which has @XmlJavaTypeAdapter?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am currently designing a generic message exchange format for a client-server communication. Within the message there is a field that will be overrided by each specific webservice. Simplified example follows:

```
class Message {
    public BasicInfo basicInfo;
}
```

`BasicInfo` is the base class. All derived classes will not have public no-args constructor. So I wrote `XmlAdapter` for them.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(...)
class SpecificInfoA extends BasicInfo {
    // Detail omitted
}
```

Then I updated the class `Message`, hoping that jaxb is able to determine the class at runtime and use corresponding adapter to transform the object...

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({SpecificInfoA.class})
class Message {
    @XmlAnyElement
    public BasicInfo basicInfo;
}
```

But when I create the `JAXBContext`:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
```

An exception is thrown:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
playground.SpecificInfoA does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at playground.SpecificInfoA
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class playground.SpecificInfoA])

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
```

Since `SpecificInfoA` has a `XmlAdapter`, I expected jaxb to be able to add it to its context, but from the exception above, is it simply impossible to do so or am I doing it wrong?

I know I can write a general `XmlAdapter` for `BasicInfo` that converts instances to a general bind type when marshalling and create specific instances back when unmarshalling. However it would tightly couple all derived classes into one adapter, which is undesired.